# For $W = \left\{y_1, \ldots, y_k \right)$ is $D_j = \left\{ x \in H: \left\| x- y_j \right\| < \left\| x- y_i \right\|, i \neq j \right\}$ convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $W = \left\{y_1, \ldots, y_k \right)$ with $y_i \in H$, a real separable Hilbert space, and define $D_j$ the set of all elements of $H$ that have $y_j$ as the closest point of $W$, that is, $D_j = \left\{ x \in H: \left\| x- y_j \right\| < \left\| x- y_i \right\|, i \neq j   \right\}$.

I would like to either prove or disprove that the set $D_j$ is convex, as one would expect. So we take $x, y \in D_j$ and we try to prove that $s := \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y \in D_j$, that is, $\left\| s-y_j \right\| < \left\| s-y_i \right\|$ for all $i\neq j$, for $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Squaring both sides we obtain the equivalent condition

$$\alpha^2 \left\| x - y_j \right\| + \left(1-\alpha\right)^2 \left\|y-y_j \right\| + 2\alpha (1-\alpha)\langle x- y_j, y- y_j \rangle < \\
\alpha^2 \left\| x - y_i \right\| + \left(1-\alpha\right)^2 \left\|y-y_i \right\| + 2\alpha (1-\alpha)\langle x- y_i, y- y_i \rangle$$

but while the first two terms are bu hypothesis smaller than the first two terms on the right, the inner product terms are not so easy to deal with. I then thought about using the projection theorem but $W$ does not meet the criteria as it is neither convex nor a closed subspace.

Therefore, I would appreciate some help here. Thank you.

Comment: Thinking of ${\mathbb R}^n$, it seems that $D_j$ is the intersection of open half-spaces.

Comment: @Gribouillis So it's not convex.

Comment: Why not? It seems to me that a half space is convex.

Comment: @Gribouillis Okay, is there a proof for general Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a real Hilbert space, one has

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\left\|x-{y}_{j}\right\|  <  \left\|x-{y}_{i}\right\|&\Longleftrightarrow &{\left\|x-{y}_{j}\right\|}^{2}  <  {\left\|x-{y}_{i}\right\|}^{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &2 \langle x , {y}_{j}\rangle+{\left\|{y}_{j}\right\|}^{2}  <  2 \langle x , {y}_{i}\rangle+{\left\|{y}_{i}\right\|}^{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\langle x , {y}_{j}-{y}_{i}\rangle  <  \displaystyle  \frac{{\left\|{y}_{i}\right\|}^{2}-\left\|{y}_{j}^{2}\right\|}{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & \varphi_{i,j}(x) < \alpha_{i, j}
\end{array}$$
where $\varphi_{i, j}(x)$ is the bounded linear functional $\langle x , {y}_{j}-{y}_{i}\rangle$

This affine half space is convex. In fact, every set defined by an equation $\varphi(x) < \alpha$ is convex, when $\varphi$ is a bounded linear functional and $\alpha$ is a real number.

$D_j$ is convex as the intersection of convex sets.

Comment: What have you shown exactly here with these equivalence relationships?

Comment: See my edits above.